# Diagonal sum projection of a matrix - how to find the original indices?

Tags: matrices

Say I have a 2 by 2 matrix [1,2 | 3,4].

I will now create two vectors which sum the entries up - one diagonally, and one vertically.

Vertical = [1+3, 2+4]

Diagonal (left) = [1, 2+3, 4]

If i want to start reconstructing the original matrix from these two vectors, I need to know which "intersection" corresponds to which entry of the original matrix.

My question is how do I determine this? I'm looking for a formula that will allow me to perform this transformation. Some examples:

Vertical[1] and Diagonal[1] = Original[1,1]

Vertical[1] and Diagonal[3] = Undefined

Vertical[2] and Diagonal[3] = Original[2.2]